# How to launch an ios app on an iphone that I cannot connect to my mac

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I have built an ios app that I have tested on the iphone simulator. I now want to run it on an iphone but the usb ports on my mac do not work. I have no way to connect my iphone to my mac. Is there any way to send a compiled version of my app to my iphone so that it can install it itself? Like you can do on android when you can send a .apk file to the phone and it can install it itself. I can register my iphone to my devices on the member center. 
Sorry for the newbie question! I just started with ios development.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your phone up to be your own "beta tester" and send it over the air via Hockey App. - http://hockeyapp.net/features/

I would suggest Testflight but with Apple buying them they might go away.

Comment: TestFlight is a perfectly reasonable way to send ad hoc builds, and I would be SHOCKED if Apple killed them. They bought them to gain their technology, not to kill it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please explain a bit more? Do I register my phone with this service? How do I download the app from there?

Comment: Also, one more thing. I have an old iphone. 3GS. I built the app in Xcode 5 for ios7. Will I be able to install the app on this iphone?

Comment: Click the link hmanso02. Hockey explains it better than I ever could. And if your phone has iOS 7, it will run.